# iOS and Android programming

Tags: android, ios, reusability

I have developed a few Android applications and am currently working on developing an iOS application from scratch. Is there any method by which I can focus on developing my iOS application in such a way that I can reuse some of its components or features for developing the same application on the Android platform?

Comment: Just to add something.  If you stick true to the MVC model, all "M" sections can be written in C++ and shared as is.  Don't try to share view or view controller code because the two environments are simply too different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any method by which I can focus on developing my iOS
>   application in such a way that I can reuse some of its components or
>   features for developing the same application on the Android platform?

You can if you use web technologies (HTML, CSS, Javascript). You can do that if you build a web-based app or a hybrid app, i.e. one that uses web-based content running inside a native shell. Look into PhoneGap if you're interested in building a hybrid app -- it offers a quick way to get started. There are also some cross-platform frameworks like [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/titanium-platform/) that purport to offer write once/run on several platforms functionality.

If you want to build an app that's fully native on both platforms, you won't be able to reuse application logic. iOS and Android use different frameworks written in different languages running on different hardware, and apps on each platform work somewhat differently as well. Even so, what you *can* re-use is whatever work you put into the infrastructure that drives the apps. Most apps rely on some sort of server infrastructure to supply or collect data, and that server component can easily serve apps running on either platform.

Comment: thanks for the info :)...i would like to know some more...can you guide me in this..say i want to develop an iOS application on some xcode s/w or any other particular software..and then i want to develop the same application on Android using java eclipse...can any ios components be reusable for this android application development?..the entire code would definitely not be reusable but any other components?

Comment: Not if it's native code. Android apps are written in Java and use the components and architecture provided by Android. iOS apps are normally written in Objective-C and use components from Cocoa Touch. As I mentioned, there are ways to try to do cross-platform development using a web-based interface or a cross-platform technology like Titanium or Adobe Air. But if you've written a native Android component, it's not going to work on iOS or vice versa.

Comment: is there any scope for any trial and research in this domain?

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing the same application, then you can use [j2objc](http://code.google.com/p/j2objc/) to translate your java (non-UI or hardware/platform specific) code to objective-c.

From the description:

> J2ObjC is an open-source command-line tool from Google that translates
>   Java code to Objective-C for the iOS (iPhone/iPad) platform. This tool
>   enables Java code to be part of an iOS application's build, as no
>   editing of the generated files is necessary. The goal is to write an
>   app's non-UI code (such as data access, or application logic) in Java,
>   which is then shared by web apps (using GWT), Android apps, and iOS
>   apps.

Comment: could you elaborate on ios to android reuse?

Comment: Ohh sorry, I misread your question... I thought you wanted it the other way around.

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but as far as I heard/read it translates java into obj-c. Keep in mind that this does *not* apply to platform-specific code (UI for example). So this is good if you want to translate your core-algorithms.

Comment: but can this be done obj-c to java for translating algorithms?

Comment: is there any scope for research in this domain?

Comment: so viceversa for ios to android not possible?...can it be tried?

Comment: I am not sure, if there is a tool, with which you can do this. At least I haven't heard of it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27807/discussion-between-tushar-gupta-and-ahmad)